# How to solve NaN when I'm deleting a number?

Tags: javascript, dom, sum

This is the code when I am adding in all textbox it works fine but after removing number it shows NaN:

```
function sumVal()
{
    var total = 0;
    var coll = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    for ( var i = 0; i<coll.length; i++)
    {
        var ele = coll[i];
        total += parseInt(ele.value);
    }
    var Display = document.getElementById("Display");
    Display.innerHTML = total;
}

<input onkeyup="sumVal()" />
<input onkeyup="sumVal()" />
<input onkeyup="sumVal()" />
```

Comment: NaN means "Not a Number."  The program is trying to tell you it can't parse the input you are giving it.

Comment: what is parseInt(ele.value) ? It is expecting an integer in the string format

Comment: Just an aside: You should add a proper `type` attribute value on your `<input /> ` elements (e.g. `<input type="text" ... />`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try checking that your value is NaN before adding it to the total:

```
total += (isNaN(parseInt(ele.value, 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(ele.value, 10));
```

Also, don't forget the radix for [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) (or use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) in the event you have decimal places):

**radix**

> An integer that represents the radix of the above mentioned string.
>   **Always specify this parameter** to eliminate reader confusion and to
>   guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce
>   different results when a radix is not specified.

```
var nums = [10, "sads", 44, 16];
var numsLen = nums.length;
var total = 0;

while(numsLen--){
    total += (isNaN(parseInt(nums[numsLen], 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(nums[numsLen], 10));
}
```

In this [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9DWMf/), since "sads" is **not a number (NaN)** we add 0 to the total.

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that the element's value is a valid number first:

```
if (isNumber(ele.value))
    total += parseInt(ele.value, 10);
}
```

You'll need this function:

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

The above function is the famous `isNumber` function [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric).

Answer (score 1):

Just add `0` is if it's not a number:

```
var theInt = parseInt(ele.value, 10);
total += (isNaN(theInt)) ? 0 : theInt;
```